# AngularJS & mocha: $httpBackend call before each test

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine, karma-mocha

I am working with angularjs and writing tests in mochajs.
I implemented multi-language support in my application and now I have the problem, that in many test-cases i get an unexpected request for my language.json

Do you have any idea how to handle this, without adding the "$httpBackend.whenGet(....." for the language-handling to each test?

Comment: Adding `$httpBackend.whenGet()` to `beforeEach()` once isn't simple enough?

Comment: I have multiple spec-files... so i should put it in each file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Mocha and Jasmine support [root-level hooks](https://mochajs.org/#root-level-hooks) (which will affect all `describe`s).

When loaded in the first place in karma, this

```
angular.module('test-setup', []).run(function ($httpBackend) {
  $httpBackend.whenGET(...
});

beforeEach(module('test-setup'));
```

should provide `$httpBackend` setup for all specs.